# How to change visibility of hidden items of RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm developing chat app. It has a feature that is reply action (like Telegram/WhatsApp). When user click replied message then a RecyclerView should scroll to declared position. But if I set position of hidded item of recyclerview, app throw a NullPoinerException. It is working for only visible items.

```
        holder.replyContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(m.content.getReply().getPosition());
                    View view = mRecyclerView.
                            findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(m.content.getReply().getPosition())
                            .itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected);
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mActivity, R.anim.fade_out));
            }
        });
```

Comment: share your error logs.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    PID: 26983
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object reference

Comment: You got `null pointer exception` because 
 `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(m.content.getReply().getPosition())` gives you `null`.

Comment: I know that, how can I change hidded items of recyclerview? Do you have any suggestion for to do it? (reply to a specific message)

Comment: have you tried mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(m.content.getReply().getPosition()-1);

Comment: It didn't work. The problem isn't on the mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position) but on the .itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected); view is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it, the invisible items of methods are must be call after scrolling finished. So, I added listener to RecyclerView:

```
RecyclerView.OnScrollListener listener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
  @Override
  public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                                   super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
      if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
          RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = (RecyclerView.ViewHolder)
                mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(replyPosition);
                      if(holder != null) {
                           View view = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected);
                           view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                           view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mActivity,
                                                   R.anim.fade_out));

                                       }

                                   }
                               }

  @Override
  public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
  }
                           };
  mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(listener);
  mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(replyPosition);
```